# Ubuntu 18.4 cant start because of mounting error - what now?

Tags: 18.04, startup, automount, restart

I started my Linux and it takes forever to start. I already know that I can press "esc" so I can see what is going on in the back. It says

```
"Failed to mount /media/x-data"
See 'systemct1 status "media-x\\x22dbigdata.mount for details.
```

How can I see systemct1? Nothing works I don't know how to access it. Also, can I force the computer to start without mounting this?

Comment: That is very likely `systemctl` (with a lowercase "L")

Comment: oooh, I see thank you!!! but how can I access this? I cant access a terminal or anything..

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44027/285436) on Unix&Linux could be helpful.